# Git workflows on remote machines?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, development-environment

I'd like to know what development flows people like to use when they are working on EC2 boxes in terms of git commits: workflow, best practices, pitfalls etc.?

Answer (score 1):

When you are already using AWS then you should probably go with CodeCommit. It is managed source control service that supports all git commands. Your data is automatically encrypted both in rest and transit. It is also highly redundant, therefore you don't need to worry about loosing the data.

Since this is a managed service, best practices and pitfalls that are related to the service are solved already by AWS. So if you are familiar with git, then all the same applies to CodeCommit (except that you don't need to worry about the service itself).

Another benefit is that you can leverage IAM policies if you have more users to allow/deny access to specific repository for a specific user or group.